# error submit form google apps script bad value

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an application that submits a form. I'm sure that my code is fine, but when I execute the application I run into this error: `error encountered script bad value`.

Here are my two functions: `doGet` writes the form and `onSumbit` submits the form into the spreadsheet

```
function doGet()
{
var Myapp= UiApp.createApplication();
var panel=Myapp.createAbsolutePanel().setStyleAttributes({'position':'fixed',
                                                        'top':'15%',
                                                        'left':'2%',
                                                        'height':'300',
                                                        'width':'500',});
var NameLabel=Myapp.createLabel().setText('Name');
var NameTb=Myapp.createTextBox().setId('Nameid').setName('Name');
var LastNameLabel=Myapp.createLabel().setText('Last name');
var LastNameTb=Myapp.createTextBox().setId('Lastnameid').setName('LastName');
var emailLABEL=Myapp.createLabel().setText('Email');
var emailtb=Myapp.createTextBox().setName('Email');
var serverHandler=Myapp.createServerHandler('onSubmitForm');
var ButtonSubmit=Myapp.createButton('submit',serverHandler);
   serverHandler.addCallbackElement(NameTb).addCallbackElement(LastNameTb).addCallbackElement(emailtb);
var panelButton =Myapp.createFlowPanel().setStyleAttributes({'position': 'fixed', 
                                                           'border' : '2px solid black',
                                                           'top' : '80%',
                                                           'left' : '70%',
                                                           'width' : '55', 
                                                           'height':'30'}); 

Myapp.add(panel);
Myapp.add(panelButton);
panel.add(NameLabel);
panel.add(NameTb);
panel.add(LastNameLabel);
panel.add(LastNameTb);
panel.add(emailLABEL);
panel.add(emailtb);
panelButton.add(ButtonSubmit);

return Myapp;
}
function onSubmitForm(e)
{
var Myapp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

var sheet     =SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Ar2BlsmmO4nZdHN6WXp2akx1QWUzX3lKX19rYzUyRVE&usp').getActiveSheet();

var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); 

sheet.getRange("A"+lastRow).setValue(e.parameter.Name);
sheet.getRange("B"+lastRow).setValue(e.parameter.LastName);
sheet.getRange("C"+lastRow).setValue(e.parameter.Email);

return Myapp;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is newSp defined?

Comment: here is my new function of the submit , but i still i have the same error, ps : i have an other function doGet , where i write my form  
function onSubmitForm(e)
{
  var Myapp = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  
  var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Ar2BlsmmO4nZdHN6WXp2akx1QWUzX3lKX19rYzUyRVE&usp').getActiveSheet();
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  
  sheet.getRange("A"+lastRow).setValue(e.parameter.Name);
  sheet.getRange("B"+lastRow).setValue(e.parameter.LastName);
  sheet.getRange("C"+lastRow).setValue(e.parameter.Email);
  
  return Myapp;
}

Comment: please edit your post with the right code rather than commenting... not very readable.

Comment: no problem, it was just a tip to improve your chances of getting appropriate help. That said, I'm afraid the code you show is not an exact copy of your real code... where is e defined ? could you show the doGet ? and why is it called "onSubmitForm" ??? normally it should be doGet / doPost... I really don't understand how you make it work.

Comment: i will put the two functions may be it ill be more clear for everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to come from the `spreadSheetApp` call, does this Id exist and have you edit access to it ?

Another point : don't use `getActiveSheet()` in that context as there is no spreadsheet open so no active sheet .... use `getSheetByName()` instead.

Last point : you are using a variable `lastRow` that does not exist.... you defined `numRows` , well use it ! (but add +1 otherwhise you will overwrite the last row each time you submit.

Here is the replacement code :(I used another ID for my test, revise the value and dubble check it)

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AnqSFd3iikE3dGFpMm1IMHo5OGZteUZSTEV6NnRUT2c').getSheetByName('Sheet1');

var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()+1; 

sheet.getRange("A"+numRows).setValue(e.parameter.Name);
sheet.getRange("B"+numRows).setValue(e.parameter.LastName);
sheet.getRange("C"+numRows).setValue(e.parameter.Email);
```

And finally, why didn't you use a more usual doGet / doPost structure, it would simplify the script as it doesn't need callbackElement and handler... ?
Also, think about adding something in the handler function to tell the user that his form has been submitted otherwise they will click it indefinitely ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help actually the error was the Id of the spreedsheet i don't know how i added '&usp' in the key of the spreadsheet, now everything work, and the think for your advice about using doPost ;)